# Make script executable from vi/vim

Tags: permissions, vi, chmod

How can I run `chmod +x` on the script I'm creating in vi/vim so that it is executable?  I tried `:r chmod +x %` but it didn't work.

Comment: I figured it out r! chmod +x %

Comment: Please don't forget to mark one of the answers as accepted or even answer your own question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need

```
:! chmod +x %
```

The `!` is used to run your commands in a shell.

Comment: What does :r do? It seems to print output from the command to the current line.  I guess it isn't needed in this case.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal `:r` reads the file you name and prints its contents starting on the next line. Try `:help :r`

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  one of these days I am going to really dig in and learn vim beyond just basic editing.

Answer (score 1):

In vim you can execute a shell command in command mode with and `!` at the beginning. So in your case you can do something like this : `:!chmod +x %`. `%` is the current file in Vim.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: How does this differ from [Joseph R's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102456/6761)?